# How to get user follower details with Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am new to twitter api, there is any way  to get user followers details similar like graph API IN facebook (without login)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. In `API v1.1`, requests without authentication are considered invalid.

Comment: anyother method to get the data in  other version

Comment: No. You need to try with authentication. No goo!

Comment: with authentication means can i use my app id and key and able to get all user details using name like this https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=rsarver

Comment: Yes. Here are some [Twitter libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries) to help you.

Comment: Hi i used this [libraries](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) and created access token, key and secret key. In $postfield screen_name not getting. I was testing in localhost value not returning.